Stream Audio from another tab to Google Meet tab using Chrome Extension
During virtual calls with friends (in Chrome and over Google Meet), I would like to stream radio for the participants. The usual way for me is to play the Radio over speakers in another tab, turn on the microphone on the GMeet tab, and let the microphone capture the audio from the Speaker. I want to know if bypassing this by using a Chrome extension is possible. The steps are,

Capture the audio from Radio (can be done using tabCapture) -- DONE
Play the audio in the Google Meet tab so that participants can hear it (??) -- PENDING

Any help with the 2nd step will be appreciated.
Thanks.

I would suggest to use Popup. Check if current tab is Google Meet. If true, play the audio file. I am not sure if autoplay is allowed by browsers or chrome extensions.
